# Android studio say static field will leak contexts

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, android-context

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169270/do-not-place-android-context-classes-in-static-fields-this-is-a-memory-leak) is a similar question but I think it is not identical

And I read Setting up request queue tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html)

In this page they write the following code

```
public class MySingleton {
   private static Context mCtx;
```

And I wrote same code in my project

```
public class VolleySingleton {
  private static Context mContext;
```

Android studio say “Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak”.
What does it mean? And why dos the official android developer website use such kind of code?

Comment: use Application context when use singeton else leaking

Comment: (Originally flagged as) Possible duplicate of [Do not place Android Context classes in static fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868001/do-not-place-android-context-classes-in-static-fields-this-is-a-memory-leak) but a **better Possible duplicate** is [Warning do not place Android Context classes in static fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094020/warning-do-not-place-android-context-classes-in-static-fields-this-is-a-memor)